# Delete row by clicking button on cell using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this table structure that I use to construct a table dynamically using jQuery.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="paper-table"><thead><tr><td><b>Pubmed ID</b></td><td><b>Title</b></td><td><b>Year</b></td><td><b>Journal</b></td><td></td></tr></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td> id </td>
    <td> title </td>
    <td> year </td>
    <td> journal </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="delete-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot><tr><span id="table-title">Paper</span></tr></tfoot></table>
```

The last column of each row is a trashcan icon that I want to make clickable to delete the row where the user clicks. The table gets constructed correctly but I need a jQuery function that will allow me to delete the row. Also it should check if the table has no more rows after deleting one and delete the table if there are no more rows. Looking at some other posts I found that I could delete the table by doing something like this

```
$('#paper-table').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

But it doesn't work when I click the trashcan icon. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure `#paper-table` exists at the time you execute that statement? [I can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/v0t6x1Ld/).

Comment: This code works fine for me. Did you check your browser console for any errors say libraries missing or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you link does delete the row in which the anchor tag is but it wont delete the table.  If your question is how to  delete the table then you will have to check if there are no more rows and then delete the table e.g. -

```js
$('#paper-table').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();

  //check if no more rows and remove the table
  if ($('#paper-table tbody tr').length == 0) {
    $('#paper-table').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="paper-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Pubmed ID</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Title</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Year</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>Journal</b>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="table-title">Footer</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>title</td>
      <td>year</td>
      <td>journal</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="delete-row">del</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>title</td>
      <td>year</td>
      <td>journal</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="delete-row">del</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure it deletes the row? It's not working for me.

Comment: @Atirag Yes definitely working, run the code snippet to check...or check the other answers jsfiddle link. Maybe the table you are dynamically generating isn't what is expected?

Comment: Weird, I was puting the code inside a document ready function like this $(document).ready(function(){*code here*} and it didn't work. Now that I put it outside of it, it is working.

Comment: Once the DOM is loaded can you check using the browser inspect element tool to determine if the table and its attributes are generated.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/082375a7/) for the working demo.
Here is the code: (extra rows has been added for testing)

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="paper-table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Pubmed ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
   <th>Year</th>
  <th>Journal</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> id 1 </td>
<td> title 1</td>
<td> year 1</td>
<td> journal 1</td>
<td><a href="#" class="delete-row" onclick="deleteThis(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> id 2</td>
<td> title2 </td>
<td> year 2</td>
<td> journal 2</td>
<td><a href="#" class="delete-row"  onclick="deleteThis(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> id 3</td>
<td> title 3 </td>
<td> year 3</td>
<td> journal 3</td>
<td><a href="#" class="delete-row"  onclick="deleteThis(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot><tr><span id="table-title">Paper</span></tr></tfoot></table>
```

**JS**

```
function deleteThis(obj){
    $(obj).closest('tr').remove();
}
```